# Mahout custom data

Tags: java, mahout, mahout-recommender, recommendation-engine

I need to make a recommendation system using mahout. My data has the following data pieces:

- userID -> The numerical id of the user
- foodID -> Contains the numerical id of the food (for example ketchup's id is 88)
- rating -> Rating the user gave the item from 1 to 5
- brandID -> The numerical id of the foodID brand (for example Heinz may be id 4)

Using the code below:

```
 UserBasedRecommender recommender;
        int userId = 5;

        try {
            File file = new File(getClass().getResource("databaseFILE.csv").getFile());
            DataModel dataModel = new FileDataModel(file);

            UserSimilarity userSimilarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel);
            UserNeighborhood userNeighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, userSimilarity, dataModel);
            recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(dataModel, userNeighborhood, userSimilarity);

            List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(userId, 5);
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                System.out.println(recommendation);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (TasteException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

This gives an output for the itemID and its corresponding value, however I get no result for the brandID. Im not sure how I would change this so that the brandID can also be included within the data structure.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I think where you said `itemID` you meant `foodID` but I think what you need to do is to combine your `foodID` AND `brandID` into a single `itemID`

Comment: Oh sorry I have fixed that, yes I have thought about combining them but i'm not sure how as my database structure is in the form that I have mentioned above.

Comment: suffice to say, i think you have a data wrangling problem, not a mahout problem. Your question then really is `How do I convert a csv file of the form: col-a,col-b,col-c to the form col-a,col-b_col-c` A tip is to look up the CONCAT or CONCATENATE functions, but really ought to be another question all together.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this I thought one way I could do it is 6 digits at the start to be for the itemID and the another  6 digits to be for the brand id. Is this something that you mean?